# Class 'JWT' not found

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, slim

I'm trying to run an authentication API using JWT.

I am currently using Slimframework v3 and PHP 7.4.1 and I'm connecting to MySQL using PDO.
I used composer to require firebase.

```
C:\Users\Desktop\php>composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

I'm getting an error message when running my API using postman saying that "Class 'JWT' not found" line 172.

```
<h1>Slim Application Error</h1>
<p>The application could not run because of the following error:</p>
<h2>Details</h2>
<div><strong>Type:</strong> Error</div>
<div><strong>Message:</strong> Class 'JWT' not found</div>
<div><strong>File:</strong> C:\Users\Desktop\php\src\routes\user.php</div>
<div><strong>Line:</strong> 172</div>
```

Code on line 172 of user.php

```
$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $secret_key);
```

Code in my index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/./vendor/autoload.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
require __DIR__.'/./src/config/db.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

require_once __DIR__.'/./src/routes/user.php';
```

This is my autoload.php

```
<?php
// autoload.php @generated by Composer
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInit23b54112a5e426a79a0f306cc05fddce::getLoader();
```

Would appreciate any help I can get on this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @FrankvanPuffelen. I will take note in the future whenever I'm posting a question.

Comment: I think the most important part is missing, what happens in user.php? My guess is, you don't `use \Firebase\JWT\JWT` in there? You have to use it in the file you call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup my code is now working when I add

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT
```

in my user.php file instead of the index.php.

Thanks @jumper85 for your answer.